# Alternative to char array as input to template parameter

Tags: c++

```
static constexpr char MyCharArray[] = "yolo";

template<const char* CharArray>
struct MyStruct {
    //Do stuff
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct<MyCharArray> myStruct;
}
```

This works great, but I want to 'clean up' my char array in the first line. It is ugly. Are there any alternatives to using the char array, such that my code still compiles and works. Thanks

Comment: Is there a better way of achieving *what*?

Comment: With `char_sequence` ?

Comment: Q: What's the point of using a template in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with for you:

1. remove the keyword `static` - it's not needed
2. shorten the definition of `MyCharArray` by using a typedef.

-

```
using chars = const char[];

constexpr chars MyCharArray = "yolo";

template<const char* CharArray>
struct MyStruct {
    //Do stuff
};

int main()
{
  MyStruct<MyCharArray> myStruct;
}
```